# Windows 10 media keys affect multiple apps at the same time

Tags: windows, windows-10, media, playback, multimedia

I have a problem on my desktop Windows 10 computer where the keyboard media keys affect every media application simultaneously. If there are for example multiple media players plus youtube in a browser open, they will all be affected by the media keys. If one of the media players have playback on and I press the play/pause media key the app stops playing and every other app STARTS playing. So every key affects every app globally.

What I want is to be able to control the app with the currently active playback. On my Lenovo work laptop this is exactly how it works.

Does anyone else have this problem and more importantly, a solution? I tried searching far and wide before asking.

Comment: This is likely a manufacturer / BIOS problem. Brand and model of your desktop? Motherboard?

Comment: So.. not to say something silly.. but the rest of us wouldn't even know if this was a problem because we don't run multiple media apps simultaneously.  What on earth are you doing??

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Spotify and YouTube videos on Chrome.. Using media keys from my keyboard affected both at the same time, not the active one.

The solution was to enable "Show desktop overlay when using media keys" on Spotify Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to this problem.

I have Windows 11, so I don't know if it will work in Windows 10. I'm not much of an expert in PC so sorry for saying the wrong name of something.

Just go to the menu where you enable Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, etc. There you'll find a notification to play/pause and etc. In the corner there's a arrow where you can chose which media you'll control. The media showing in this notification is the media you'll be able to control with the media keys.

Sorry for the bad English. I'm Brazilian.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ0pH.png)